# Can this fluent interface be simplified?

Tags: c#, generics, fluent-interface

I am trying to implement a fluent interface that let's me specify a table with columns, where table and columns have properties. I want to able to initialize the table class like this:

```
var t = TableBuilder.Create()
                    .WithName("test") 
                    .WithColumn("col1").WithType("Int32")
                    .WithColumn("col2").WithType("String")
                    .WithColumn("col3");
```

I came up with a solution, that works. My questions are, can the implementation be simplified or should I take a totally different approach? I've seen the usage of extension methods in similar cases, but I don't know if they would help me or how to use them in this case.

Here is the code (with some comments below):

```
interface ITable
{
    ITable WithName(string tableName);
    ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn> WithColumn(string columnName);
}

interface IColumn
{
    IColumn WithType(string typeName);
}

interface ITableAndColum<TTable, TColumn>
    where TTable : ITable
    where TColumn : IColumn
{
    ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn> WithColumn(string columnName);
    ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn> WithType(string typeName);
}

class TableAndColumn : ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn>
{
    public ITable Table { get; set; }
    public IColumn Column { get; set; }

    public ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn> WithColumn(string columnName)
    {
        return Table.WithColumn(columnName);
    }

    public ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn> WithType(string typeName)
    {
        Column.WithType(typeName);
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Table.ToString();
    }
}

class Column : IColumn
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public IColumn WithType(string typeName)
    {
        TypeName = typeName;
        return this;
    }
}

class TableBuilder : ITable
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    List<Column> Columns;

    TableBuilder() { Columns = new List<Column>(); }

    public static ITable Create() { return new TableBuilder(); }

    public ITable WithName(string tableName)
    {
        TableName = tableName;
        return this;
    }

    public ITableAndColum<ITable, IColumn> WithColumn(string columnName)
    {
        Column thisColumn = new Column() { ColumnName = columnName };
        Columns.Add(thisColumn);

        return new TableAndColumn() { Table = this, Column = thisColumn };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TableName + "(" + string.Join(",", Columns.Select(c => (c.TypeName != null ? c.TypeName + " " : "") + c.ColumnName)) + ")";
    }
}

class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        var t = TableBuilder.Create()
                            .WithName("test")
                            .WithColumn("col1").WithType("Int32")
                            .WithColumn("col2").WithType("String")
                            .WithColumn("col3");
        var tdef = t.ToString();
    }

}
```

There are the two interfaces `ITable` and `IColumn` with there implementations `Table` and `Colum`. They expose the appropriate methods which are specific to their type. The third interface `ITableAndColumn` combines the other interfaces and it's implementation `TableAndColumn` holds a reference to a Table instance and a Column instance. The Interface exposes selected methods of `ITable` and `IColumn` and calls the appropriate instance.

Is this approach to complicated? Would extension methods simply this in any way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you opposed to using designing your API to use the traditional style?

Comment: Answers to this question are going to be pretty biased, but then so is my comment - as a personal preference I would like the `WithType` method to be called `AndType` so you get `WithColumn("col1").AndType("Int32")` and I would rather have the types be defined using actual `Type`s rather than strings..

Comment: I wanted to make my API more readable. Of course that only works with proper indention and line breaks of the code and if the chain doesn't get too long, but I can live with both draw backs. And I know that I could use simpler method chaining with constructor initializers and name parameters. But I still want to know how some api do what I illustrated in my sample code.

Comment: @MikeDinescu: You are right about WithType/AndType. I keep that in mind. You are also right about actual types beeing passed to that method. I wanted to keep it a little simpler for the above code. That is why I chose the paremeter to be string.

Comment: @MikeDinescu: As a side question: In the same sense as you would name WithType rathrer AndType, would you name ITableAndColumn.IsNullable rather ITableAndColumn.WhichIsNullable if that method would work on a property of Colum?

Comment: @Sascha - I guess it depends on what feels more readable. On one hand `WhichIsNullable` is harder to read because it's longer but it's more explicit..

Comment: @MikeDinescu: Agreed. I kneew the question was opinion based, but I was still curious.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a huge fan of making `TableAndColumn`. Seems wrong, to me. They're distinct entities. I've taken a page out of KendoUI in terms of their fluent style:

```
TableBuilder.Create()
    .WithName("test")
    .WithColumn(c => c.WithName("col1").WithType("Int32"))
    .WithColumn(c => c.WithName("col2").WithType("String"))
    .WithColumn(c => c.WithName("col3"));
```

Note how we're configuring the columns via a lambda. This allows us to properly constrain what `IColumn` can expose.

Of course, you can change it to: `WithColumn("col1", c => c.WithType("Int32"))` and the overload `.WithColumn("col3")`.

Implementation:

```
interface ITable
{
    ITable WithColumn(Action<IColumn> c);
    ITable WithName(string tableName);  
}

interface IColumn
{
    IColumn WithName(string columnName);
    IColumn WithType(string typeName);
}

class TableBuilder : ITable
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    List<Column> Columns = new List<Column>();

    public static ITable Create() { return new TableBuilder(); }

    public ITable WithName(string tableName)
    {
        TableName = tableName;
        return this;
    }

    public ITable WithColumn(Action<IColumn> c) 
    { 
        Column thisColumn = new Column();
        c(thisColumn);
        Columns.Add(thisColumn);

        return this;
    }
}

class Column : IColumn
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public IColumn WithName(string columnName)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        return this;
    }

    public IColumn WithType(string typeName)
    {
        TypeName = typeName;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, TableAndColumn is a workaround to expose methods of the separate classes and let the combined class choose which method to call. That is one of the reasons why I would like to simplify my approach. Your suggestions works around that problem quite well, but it make the code less readable (IMHO).

Comment: @Sascha Yep, I agree. However, my main issue with the `TableAndColumn` is that there will potentially be another child property (let's say `Rows`, even if it doesn't quite make sense here). Then you'll need `TableAndRow` and `TableAndColumn` and `TableAndColumnAndRow`. That will get out of hand very very fast. I agree the lamdba approach is slightly less readable, but it *does* give you the benefit while writing that you know you're working with an `IColumn`, not a `TableAndColumn` (which isn't really clear what you can do). Especially if a column had the same method as the table ie `Name()`